# Oracle get day name returns wrong name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using this to get the name of a given date, so the following gives me MONDAY:

```
Select to_char(to_date('01/04/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DAY') from dual
```

However if I apply the same thing to a table and extract dates with their names I am getting a wrong day name, in the case of '01/April/2013' it gives me SATURDAY.

```
    Select to_char(to_date(myDateColumn,'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DAY'), myDateColumn 
From myTable WHERE myDateColumn = to_date('01/04/2013','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

This is how I would have done on MS SQL, but I need to do this for Oracle 10g database, is this the right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your date column is a date:

```
Select to_char(myDateColumn, 'DAY'), myDateColumn 
From myTable 
WHERE myDateColumn = to_date('01/04/2013','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

should suffice

(this should be a comment, not an answer but it wouldn't be readable)

Answer (score 6):

This is partially following up other answers, but explaining (hopefully) what's happening.

When you do this, assuming `myDateColumn` is a `DATE`:

```
to_char(to_date(myDateColumn,'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DAY')
```

you have an implicit conversion; it's really doing this:

```
to_char(to_date(to_char(myDateColumn),'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DAY')
```

which is:

```
to_char(to_date(to_char(myDateColumn, <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>),'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DAY')
```

Since you get `SATURDAY`, it looks like maybe your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `'DD/MM/YY'`, or at least that's the only way I've found to duplicate this so far:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

select date '2013-04-01' date1,
    to_char(date '2013-04-01', 'Day') day1,
    to_date(to_char(date '2013-04-01', 'dd/mm/yy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') date2,
    to_char(to_date(to_char(date '2013-04-01', 'dd/mm/yy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
        'Day') day2
from dual;

DATE1      DAY1      DATE2      DAY2
---------- --------- ---------- ---------
01/04/2013 Monday    01/04/0013 Saturday
```

So even though your `myDateColumn` really holds `2013-04-01`, your implcit conversion means it's being treated as `0013-04-01`, which is (apparently) a Saturday.

You could specify the format and make it an explicit `to_char()` inside the `to_date()`, but hopefully it's clear that's pointless, and it's much simpler to do as vc74 suggested and just drop the extra - erronerous - `to_date()` call:

```
select to_char(myDateColumn, 'DAY'), ...
```

It's maybe worth pointing out that the text produced by `DAY` is also dependent on your NLS settings; see the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch9sql.htm#i1005917) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#sthref179), for example. If you wanted to make sure it was always `MONDAY`, in English, you could force that as part of the conversion, though I don't think it looks like it'll be a consideration here:

```
select to_char(myDateColumn, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'), ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the data type for myDateColumn.

You imply that it is a date with:

```
WHERE myDateColumn = to_date('01/04/2013','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

... but also that it is a string with:

```
to_char(to_date(myDateColumn,'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DAY')
```

See what it really is, and do not convert dates to dates or compare strings to dates.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason there is to_char is to extract the name of the day from the date.

Comment: It's the to_date() inside it that I'm referring to -- if the column is already a date then you don't need to do that.